# When should use "use" and when "require" and when "AUTOLOAD" in perl [good programming practice]?

Tags: perl

When should we use "use" and when "require"  and when "AUTOLOAD" in `perl` ? I need a thumb rule for this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`use` is equivalent to `BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }`

So, the main difference is that:

- Use is used at compile time
- Use automatically calls import subroutine (which can do *anything* but mostly used to export identifiers into caller's namespace)
- use dies if the module can not be loaded (missing/compile error)

**As such:**

- When you need to load modules dynamically (for example, determine which module to load based on command line arguments), use `require`.
- In general, when you need to precisely control when a module is loaded, use `require` (`use` will load the module right after the preceding `use` or `BEGIN` block, **at compile time**).
- When you need to somehow bypass calling module's `import()` subroutine, use `require`
- When you need to do something smart as far as handling load errors (missing module, module can't compile), you can wrap the `require` into an `eval { }` statement, so the whole program doesn't just die.

  You can simulate that with `use` but in rather in-elegant ways (trapping `die` signal in an early `BEGIN` block should work). But `eval { require }` is better.
- In all OTHER cases, use `use`

I didn't cover AUTOLOAD as that's a different beastie. Its usage is in cases when you want to intercpt calls to subroutines that you haven't imported into your namespace.

Comment: In short, you generally want "use".  AUTOLOAD is for interceping calls to undefined methods.

Comment: From manual: *If you do not want to call the package's "import" method (for instance, to stop your namespace from being altered), explicitly supply the empty list:* `use Module ();`

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil - does empty list skip calling `import()` or simply calls `import()` with empty list and thus doesn't result in imports?